# Activity with viewpager at the south part and support api-10?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I'm looking into the possibility of adding a viewpager at the south/ bottom part of the screen of my activity that is supposed to hold a part of a limited list since I've run into a problem with performance.

The list of items are clickable. I make some fields visible and the list gets pushed down when an item is clicked for the information to be visible of that item.

I need to support api-10.

I've looked at actionbarsherlock and to me it does not seem possible to add that to the south part of an activity.

Any suggestions?

Comment: south part :O, means direction ?

Comment: South/bottom part of the screen.